# How JavaScript interfaces with browser's internal DOM tree

Tags: javascript, performance, dom, browser, dhtml

Memory- and performance-wise, I'm wondering what the difference is between a browser loading/parsing an `index.html` file like so:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Whatever</title></head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" id="someButton" value="Push Me!" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Or dynamically creating the same button via JavaScript:

```
var element = document.createElement("input");

element.setAttribute("type", "button");
element.setAttribute("id", "someButton");
element.setAttribute("value", "Push Me!");
```

My *suspicion* is that the latter method is slower, because first the button must be created inside the JavaScript engine's heap/cache (?) and then somehow, JavaScript must tell the browser to add the button to its DOM tree.

Is my suspicion correct? If not, why? If so, then what about the memory considerations for both methods? I feel like the former is faster in terms of manipulating the browser's DOM tree, but does it have a smaller memory footprint as well?

Comment: Have you tried testing this?

Comment: I could set up a test for speed, but no clue how to test for memory consumption. Was hoping some battle-weary JavaScript veteran might be able to weigh-in on that one.

Comment: Just google browser memory consumption, or just open up the debugger.